# Not able to install SDK Tools in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

[image: no sdk platfroms list]

I've installed android studio and it should automatically download the sdk and other components on the first launch but it didn't, also I should be able to download the sdk tools from the sdk manager but also there no list for any downloads option. I found an answer here telling that you have to download the command line tool and then extract at it and configure it, but android studio won't let me open a project unless I have the sdk. I'd appreciate your help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just try to reinstall Android Studio.

Comment: @KaranMehta  i've done that already  but the same problem remains :(

Comment: Please share some screenshot or some more information of the issue that you're facing.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzp5j.png

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved
All I did is changing the input language of my pc. After searching for a solution I found someone says that the latest android studio versions does not support Arabic language. Once I changed the input language to English I was able to download the sdk and the build tool on android studio
Thanks